# Проблемы с media queries при верстке email писем

Tags: html, css, email

Вопрос о  media queries.

Учусь верстке email писем. Необходимо создать адаптивное письмецо,  с помощью команды "display:block" преобразовать отображение ячеек таблицы из горизонтального в вертикальное если ширина отображения меньше 618px.

Данный код работает на компуктере. Перенос блоков "td" и смена цвета текста на красный происходит.

Однако на телефонах (Iphone 4 и Iphone 5) в стандартном приложении для писем перенос блоков "td" НЕ происходит, блоки продолжают выстраиваться по горизонтали, а не по вертикале, но цвет текста меняется.

Вот и вопрос, почему телефон отказывается выполнять именно "display:block" ??

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style type="text/css">
            @media only screen and (max-width:618px) {
            .td-small{display:block;!important;width:100%!important;box-sizing:border-box!important; color: red;} 
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <table align="center" style="max-width: 600px; min-width: 320px; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>

                                <td class="td-small" align="center" > 

                                <img width="120px" src="https://abonentconsult.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Continuity-Keypad-icon.png">
                                <br> 
                                123

                                </td>

                                <td class="td-small" align="center" >

                                <img width="120px" src="https://abonentconsult.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Continuity-Keypad-icon.png">
                                <br> 
                                123 

                                </td>

                                <td class="td-small" align="center" >

                                <img width="120px" src="https://abonentconsult.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Continuity-Keypad-icon.png">
                                <br> 
                                123 

                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Наверно не стоит пологаться на `<style/>`. Когда я верстал письма, половина или почти все клиенты почтовые игнорили его. Мжб сейчас что-то поменялось. Но без этого тега адаптивные стили не применятся... поэтому мой комент может быть бесполезен =)

Comment: Дело в том, что на телефоне меняется цвет текста 
,этот стиль задан в "@media", если ширина не более 618 px. То есть "style" работает и воспринимается, но вот именно команда 'display:block' не выполняется

Comment: Разные клиенты могут обрабатывать письма по разному. https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/, https://blog.mailup.com/2019/01/rendering-emails/?pd=0dfb32f1ce596 мжб чем-то поможет.

Comment: Вёрстка email-писем очень отличается от современной вёрстки сайтов.
До сих пор здесь используются таблицы.
Рекомендую почитать эти статьи, чтобы понять суть вёрстки Email-писем. [Верстка email рассылок от А до Я для чайников](https://habr.com/ru/post/252279/) [Гид по верстке адаптивных писем](https://habr.com/ru/company/netologyru/blog/324970/) [Как верстать email письма — особенности и примеры кода](https://sendpulse.com/ru/blog/html-coding-for-email)